# how to use selenium to get the element span in href

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get the specific span with required time text such as `'Yoga on 20170526 Friday  12:10'` or other time, and its xpath seems like

```
".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid']/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/header/h4/a/span[2]"
pasted html content:
<ul class="temp j-browse-thumbnails j-thumb-view" style="position: relative; width: auto; height: 780px; overflow: visible;"><li class="js-browse-thumbnail" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18277" aria-labelledby="label-96891546-18277" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div class="card"><div class="j-content-thumb j-doc-thumb j-thumb js-browse-item face card-front flippable" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18277"><header class="js-thumb-header"><h4 style="padding-right: 10px;"><a href="https://inside.com/events/18277" title="Yoga on 20170524 Wednesday&nbsp; 12:10"><span class="jive-icon-big jive-icon-med jive-icon-event"></span><span class="js-header-text j-header-text">Yoga on 20170524 Wednesday&nbsp; 12:10</span></a></h4></header><section><article><div>5/24/17 12:10 PM</div>请注意：   •12:10 - 13:10; Gym •报名成功名单（本次限报9人） •请回复你的邮箱作为 Comment •负责人会当天给报名成功同学发invitation, 报名成功的同学也可以查看Comment的时间 •报名成功却不能来，需提前24小时取消，不然未来3次不可以报名（黑名单）  （* 当周一下午2点开放报名，提前报名的不算哈 *）</article><div class="j-author-block"><span class="j-avatar-container"><a href="https://inside.com/people/xiak" title="Kelly  Xia" class="j-avatar  jiveTT-hover-user" data-userid="84832" data-online="false" data-presence="null" data-externalid="" data-avatarid="5464" data-username="xiak"><img class="jive-avatar" src="./Project_ Social Clubs _ Inside DELL_files/26.png" data-avatarid="5464" data-username="xiak" data-height="26" data-random="3197225683620284" alt="Kelly  Xia" title="Kelly  Xia" width="26" height="26"></a></span><div class="j-author-info font-color-meta"><span>created by</span> <span class="j-line2"><a href="https://inside.com/people/xiak" data-username="xiak" data-avatarid="5464" data-userid="84832" data-online="false" data-presence="null" data-externalid="" class="jive-username-link  jiveTT-hover-user  ">Kelly  Xia</a></span></div></div></section><footer><div class="j-thumb-footer"><ul class="j-stats"><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-like"></span><label class="j-508-label" id="showLikes-18277-96891546-count-label">Show 0 Likes</label><a class="j-meta-number" data-command="showLikes" data-object-id="18277" data-object-type="96891546" data-count="0" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" role="button" aria-labelledby="showLikes-18277-96891546-count-label">0</a></li><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-bookmark"></span><label class="j-508-label" id="showBookmarks-18277-96891546-count-label">Show 0 Bookmarks</label><a class="j-meta-number" data-command="showBookmarks" data-object-id="18277" data-object-type="96891546" data-count="0" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" role="button" aria-labelledby="showBookmarks-18277-96891546-count-label">0</a></li><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-comment"></span>12</li></ul><span class="j-thumb-title-meta"></span></div></footer><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="j-card-flipper j-ui-elem">Actions</a></div><div class="j-thumb-back face card-back j-thumb-back-small"><header><h6><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-med jive-icon-event"></span>Yoga on 20170524 Wednesday&nbsp; 12:10</h6><p class="j-browse-content-location font-color-meta-light">in <a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs" class="font-color-meta-light jivecontainerTT-hover-container" data-objectid="8410" data-objecttype="600">Social Clubs</a></p></header><ul class="j-social-actions" role="toolbar" aria-label="Social Actions"><li class="j-js-follow-controls" data-location="browse" data-streamsassoc="1" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"><span class="start-follow"><a class="button j-follow-button j-social-action" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18277" style="display: none;"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-follow"></span>Follow</span></a></span><span class="following"><a class="button j-follow-button j-social-action" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18277"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-follow"></span>Following <span class="j-js-streams-assoc-count j-instream-count">in <span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-activity-pulse-active j-instreamicon"></span> 1</span></span></a></span></li><li><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="share-link j-meta-control j-social-action" title="Quickly share this content with a person or group of people" data-command="share" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18277"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-share"></span>Share</span></a></li><li class="js-bookmark"><a class="bookmark-content j-social-action" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18277" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-bookmark-ribbonaction-grey"></span>Bookmark</span></a><a class="bookmarked-content j-social-action" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18277" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" style="display: none;"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-bookmark-ribbonaction"></span>Bookmarked</span></a><div class="js-bookmark-actions j-menu" style="display: none;"><ul><li><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="edit-bookmark" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18277">Edit</a></li><li><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="unbookmark-content" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18277" data-bookmarkid="-1">Remove</a></li></ul></div></li></ul><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="j-back-btn j-ui-elem"><span class="j-ui-elem">Back</span></a></div></div></li><li class="js-browse-thumbnail" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18278" aria-labelledby="label-96891546-18278" style="position: absolute; left: 245px; top: 0px;"><div class="card"><div class="j-content-thumb j-doc-thumb j-thumb js-browse-item face card-front flippable" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18278"><header class="js-thumb-header"><h4 style="padding-right: 10px;"><a href="https://inside.com/events/18278" title="Yoga on 20170526 Friday&nbsp; 12:10"><span class="jive-icon-big jive-icon-med jive-icon-event"></span><span class="js-header-text j-header-text">Yoga on 20170526 Friday&nbsp; 12:10</span></a></h4></header><section><article><div>5/26/17 12:10 PM</div>请注意：   •12:10 - 13:10; Gym •报名成功名单（本次限报9人） •请回复你的邮箱作为 Comment •负责人会当天给报名成功同学发invitation, 报名成功的同学也可以查看Comment的时间 •报名成功却不能来，需提前24小时取消，不然未来3次不可以报名（黑名单）  （* 当周一下午2点开放报名，提前报名的不算哈 *）</article><div class="j-author-block"><span class="j-avatar-container"><a href="https://inside.com/people/xiak" title="Kelly  Xia" class="j-avatar  jiveTT-hover-user" data-userid="84832" data-online="false" data-presence="null" data-externalid="" data-avatarid="5464" data-username="xiak"><img class="jive-avatar" src="./Project_ Social Clubs _ Inside DELL_files/26.png" data-avatarid="5464" data-username="xiak" data-height="26" data-random="3197225686466078" alt="Kelly  Xia" title="Kelly  Xia" width="26" height="26"></a></span><div class="j-author-info font-color-meta"><span>last modified by</span> <span class="j-line2"><a href="https://inside.com/people/xiak" data-username="xiak" data-avatarid="5464" data-userid="84832" data-online="false" data-presence="null" data-externalid="" class="jive-username-link  jiveTT-hover-user  ">Kelly  Xia</a></span></div></div></section><footer><div class="j-thumb-footer"><ul class="j-stats"><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-like"></span><label class="j-508-label" id="showLikes-18278-96891546-count-label">Show 0 Likes</label><a class="j-meta-number" data-command="showLikes" data-object-id="18278" data-object-type="96891546" data-count="0" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" role="button" aria-labelledby="showLikes-18278-96891546-count-label">0</a></li><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-bookmark"></span><label class="j-508-label" id="showBookmarks-18278-96891546-count-label">Show 0 Bookmarks</label><a class="j-meta-number" data-command="showBookmarks" data-object-id="18278" data-object-type="96891546" data-count="0" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" role="button" aria-labelledby="showBookmarks-18278-96891546-count-label">0</a></li><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-comment"></span>12</li></ul><span class="j-thumb-title-meta"></span></div></footer><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="j-card-flipper j-ui-elem">Actions</a></div><div class="j-thumb-back face card-back j-thumb-back-small"><header><h6><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-med jive-icon-event"></span>Yoga on 20170526 Friday&nbsp; 12:10</h6><p class="j-browse-content-location font-color-meta-light">in <a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs" class="font-color-meta-light jivecontainerTT-hover-container" data-objectid="8410" data-objecttype="600">Social Clubs</a></p></header><ul class="j-social-actions" role="toolbar" aria-label="Social Actions"><li class="j-js-follow-controls" data-location="browse" data-streamsassoc="1" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"><span class="start-follow"><a class="button j-follow-button j-social-action" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18278" style="display: none;"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-follow"></span>Follow</span></a></span><span class="following"><a class="button j-follow-button j-social-action" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18278"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-follow"></span>Following <span class="j-js-streams-assoc-count j-instream-count">in <span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-activity-pulse-active j-instreamicon"></span> 1</span></span></a></span></li><li><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="share-link j-meta-control j-social-action" title="Quickly share this content with a person or group of people" data-command="share" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18278"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-share"></span>Share</span></a></li><li class="js-bookmark"><a class="bookmark-content j-social-action" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18278" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-bookmark-ribbonaction-grey"></span>Bookmark</span></a><a class="bookmarked-content j-social-action" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18278" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" style="display: none;"><span><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-bookmark-ribbonaction"></span>Bookmarked</span></a><div class="js-bookmark-actions j-menu" style="display: none;"><ul><li><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="edit-bookmark" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18278">Edit</a></li><li><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="unbookmark-content" data-objecttype="96891546" data-objectid="18278" data-bookmarkid="-1">Remove</a></li></ul></div></li></ul><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="j-back-btn j-ui-elem"><span class="j-ui-elem">Back</span></a></div></div></li><li class="js-browse-thumbnail" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18279" aria-labelledby="label-96891546-18279" style="position: absolute; left: 490px; top: 0px;"><div class="card"><div class="j-content-thumb j-doc-thumb j-thumb js-browse-item face card-front flippable" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18279"><header class="js-thumb-header"><h4 style="padding-right: 10px;"><a href="https://inside.com/events/18279" title="Yoga on 20170531 Wednesday&nbsp; 12:10"><span class="jive-icon-big jive-icon-med jive-icon-event"></span><span class="js-header-text j-header-text">Yoga on 20170531 Wednesday&nbsp; 12:10</span></a></h4></header><section><article><div>5/31/17 12:10 PM</div>请注意：   •12:10 - 13:10; Gym •报名成功名单（本次限报9人） •请回复你的邮箱作为 Comment •负责人会当天给报名成功同学发invitation, 报名成功的同学也可以查看Comment的时间 •报名成功却不能来，需提前24小时取消，不然未来3次不可以报名（黑名单）  （* 当周一下午2点开放报名，提前报名的不算哈 *）</article><div class="j-author-block"><span class="j-avatar-container"><a href="https://inside.com/people/xiak" title="Kelly  Xia" class="j-avatar  jiveTT-hover-user" data-userid="84832" data-online="false" data-presence="null" data-externalid="" data-avatarid="5464" data-username="xiak"><img class="jive-avatar" src="./Project_ Social Clubs _ Inside DELL_files/26.png" data-avatarid="5464" data-username="xiak" data-height="26" data-random="3197225688764372" alt="Kelly  Xia" title="Kelly  Xia" width="26" height="26"></a></span><div class="j-author-info font-color-meta"><span>created by</span> <span class="j-line2"><a href="https://inside.com/people/xiak" data-username="xiak" data-avatarid="5464" data-userid="84832" data-online="false" data-presence="null" data-externalid="" class="jive-username-link  jiveTT-hover-user  ">Kelly  Xia</a></span></div></div></section><footer><div class="j-thumb-footer"><ul class="j-stats"><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-like"></span><label class="j-508-label" id="showLikes-18279-96891546-count-label">Show 0 Likes</label><a class="j-meta-number" data-command="showLikes" data-object-id="18279" data-object-type="96891546" data-count="0" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" role="button" aria-labelledby="showLikes-18279-96891546-count-label">0</a></li><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-bookmark"></span><label class="j-508-label" id="showBookmarks-18279-96891546-count-label">Show 0 Bookmarks</label><a class="j-meta-number" data-command="showBookmarks" data-object-id="18279" data-object-type="96891546" data-count="0" href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" role="button" aria-labelledby="showBookmarks-18279-96891546-count-label">0</a></li><li><span class="jive-icon-sml jive-icon-meta-comment"></span>0</li></ul><span class="j-thumb-title-meta"></span></div></footer><a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[event]~event[upcoming]&amp;query=yoga&amp;sortKey=contentstatus[published]~subjectAsc&amp;sortOrder=1#" class="j-card-flipper j-ui-elem">Actions</a></div><div class="j-thumb-back face card-back j-thumb-back-small"><header><h6><span class="jive-icon-med jive-icon-med jive-icon-event"></span>Yoga on 20170531 Wednesday&nbsp; 12:10</h6><p class="j-browse-content-location font-color-meta-light">in <a href="https://inside.com/groups/chinacoe/projects/social-clubs" class="font-color-meta-light jivecontainerTT-hover-container" data-objectid="8410" data-objecttype="600">Social Clubs</a></p></header><ul class="j-social-actions" role="toolbar" aria-label="Social Actions">
</ul>
```

Comment: Edit your question with code as a snippet, not as an image.

Comment: I have tried by xpath as follows, but failed. #browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid']/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/header/h4/a/descendant::span[text()='Yoga on 20170526 Friday  12:10']").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid']/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/header/h4/a/span[2]").click()

Comment: Share `HTML` code sample for the same and/or page `URL`

Comment: <a href="/events/18278" title="Yoga on 20170526 Friday  12:10">
<span class="jive-icon-big jive-icon-med jive-icon-event"/>
<span class="js-header-text j-header-text">Yoga on 20170526 Friday  12:10</span>
</a>

Comment: I have tried this:                                                                                 all_classes = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid']/ul")
for yoga_class in all_classes:
    all_lines = yoga_class.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    #then i want to for_each all_lines and call get_attributes, but it has no this function. why?

Comment: try `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a span.js-header-text.j-header-text").click()`

Comment: Thanks @kushal   It can works for this case with your method, but there are several span with different time.
And i need to click the one with the required time.

Comment: you can try this : `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a//span[contains(text(),'" yourTimeValueHere + "']").click()`

Comment: @kushal i tried your command and got this error "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "a span.js-header-text.j-header-text:contains("20170602 Friday  12:10")" is invalid:"

Comment: @winnie : yeah sorry; that was incorrect; try with the `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a//span[contains(text(),'" yourTimeValueHere + "']").click()`

Comment: @kushal It hit another issue. 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a//span[contains(text(),'Yoga on 20170602 Friday  12:10')]

Comment: @winnie try this : `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a//span[contains(text(),'" yourTimeValueHere + "')]").click()`

Comment: @kushal  it does not work. All the spans i want to get are in the path like this ".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1‌​]/header/h4/a/span[2‌​]", and they are in different li elements, i.e., they only have the same path ".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul".

Comment: <li class="js-browse-thumbnail" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18278" aria-labelledby="label-96891546-18278" >
<div class="card">
<div class="j-content-thumb j-doc-thumb j-thumb js-browse-item face card-front flippable" data-object-type="96891546" data-object-id="18278">
<header class="js-thumb-header">
<h4 style="padding-right: 10px;">
<a href="/events/18278" title="Yoga on 20170526 Friday  12:10">
<span class="jive-icon-big jive-icon-med jive-icon-event"/>
<span class="js-header-text j-header-text">Yoga on 20170526 Friday  12:10</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following, it seems you have multiple spans to click:

For List 1:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1‌​]/head‌​er/h4/a/span[contains(text(),'" + yourTimeValueHere + "')]").click()
```

For List 2:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul/li[2]/div/div[1‌​]/head‌​er/h4/a/span[contains(text(),'" + yourTimeValueHere + "')]").click()
```

For List 3:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul/li[3]/div/div[1‌​]/head‌​er/h4/a/span[contains(text(),'" + yourTimeValueHere + "')]").click()
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Generic Locator:

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul//li/div/div[1‌​]/head‌​er/h4/a/span[contains(text(),'" + yourTimeValueHere + "')]").click()
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe#wysiwyg_id_0_ifr')
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#tinymce > p').send_keys('your text here')
```

Comment: The spans i want to get are in different xpan like ".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul/li*/div/div[1]/header/h4/a/span[2]", ie., they are in different li.
It is ok using "browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​‌​]/ul/li[1]/div/div‌​[1‌​]/header/h4/a/sp‌​an[2‌​]").click()" after time.sleep(10). But all the other methods can not work. It still raised error "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: "

Comment: Thanks@kushal But it still can not work. And i updated my question with part of html content. Please help to try with this html content if convenient.

Comment: I need to get the span object with required time, and i don't know  in which li this span is. So I don't use li[1] or li[2]... in which li depends on the time text of span. You can see my html content. These spans are in the different li.

Comment: @winnie :in my answer Generic Locator should work for you, can you explain what's the problem with that?

Comment: @winnie: try with generic locator and let me know

Comment: also don't include the time part; just provide your string till the day

Comment: Still hit this syntax issue "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: <exception str() failed>", even i use browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul[1]/li/div/div[1‌​]/head‌​er/h4/a/span[contains(text(),'yoga')]").

Comment: You can save the html content to a html file, then help to try with your method if convenient. Since i have tried so many times, it still can not work. Thanks!

Comment: yep I've done that; working well for me; you need to use GEneric locator from my answer and provide text string as "Yoga on 20170526 Friday" without Time part

Comment: Yes, i just use the GEneric locator you given, but it hit issue "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: <exception str() failed>".
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul//li/div/div[1‌​]/head‌​er/h4/a/span[contains(text(),'" + 'Yoga on 20170531' + "')]")

Comment: This works well for me, you got to show me url if possible

Comment: You can't access this url which is internal. I hit this issue "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression ".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul//li/div/div[1‌​]/head‌​er/h4/a/span[contains(text(),'Yoga on 20170526 Friday')]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression." when executing "browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul//li/div/div[1‌​]/head‌​er/h4/a/span[contains(text(),'" + 'Yoga on 20170526 Friday' + "')]")". 
Why is it invalid?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. You are right. I know the root cause is there are several non-ascii characters in this expression at last.

Comment: I want to get another element with its xpath ".//*[@id='tinymce']/p", but failed. And it seems like that this element is in a iframe, then it still failed using "browser.switch_to.frame("iframe")".
Could you give me your email? I want to send you the html files.

Comment: I have sent you an email.

Comment: Thanks! It is great. Then i need to submit the input, but why i can not get the element "ADD COMMENT" with "browser.find_element_by_name("post")"? 

part html code:
<div id="jive-blog-comment-preview" class="jive-blog-comment-preview" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="jive-form-buttons">
<input class="j-btn-callout" name="post" value="Add Comment" type="submit">
<input name="cancel" value="Cancel" type="button">
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

Comment: because that button is not on iframe and you've currently switched on to iframe, so first you need to switch back from frame using `browser.switch_to_default_content()`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am a selenium beginner. Could you give me some suggestion about how to learn selenium well?

Comment: Okay.. take any sample web application, start automating it and use stack overflow as much you can. Plus go visit toolsqa.com and guru99.com. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few xpath-based options based on the HTML in the comments. Here is the one I'd try first:

```
a_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Yoga on 20170526 Friday 12:10']")
span_element = a_element.find_element_by_class_name("js-header-text")
```

another option:

```
span_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='Yoga on 20170526 Friday 12:10']")
```

Comment: @Ramendik But it can not work with these two methods.
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@title='Yoga on 20170526 Friday 12:10']

Comment: In this case, search the inspected source of the entire page for <iframe> elements. The element might be in a frame. In this case, Selenium needs to be switched to the frame to find it.

Comment: I think it is a special case. I try to find the span element with its accurate xpath, but it still can not find the element. 
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid'‌​]/ul/li[1]/div/div[1‌​]/header/h4/a/span[2‌​]").click() 
 ================= error info: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .//*[@id='j-browse-item-grid']/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/header/h4‌​/a/span[2] –

Comment: This is exactly what happens if the element is inside an iframe, so it is very important to check